# jPlayer in iPhone web app

Tags: jquery, streaming, jplayer

I need to do a simple stream audio player for iPhone.
How can i do this with jPlayer ?

I haven't find any tutorial in official site to solve my question or for simple stream audio.

Answer (score 0):

jPlayer actually has a very nice quick start guide at http://www.jplayer.org/latest/quick-start-guide/step-1/

In your case choose "next step for audio" in step 5.

To make it work virtually everywhere you have to provide mp3 and m4a files of the audio to jPlayer.